# Счётчик начинал отсчёт только когда он попадёт в видимую область

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть js счётчик чисел jquery.countTo.js. При загрузки страницы он вызывается и сразу запускается, но счётчик находится в средине страницы и при скролле вниз страницы уже не видно того анимационного эффекта. 
Поэтому использую плагин  [WayPoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) для того чтобы скрипт выполнялся только при достижении определенного блока. 
Но после того, как я подключил WayPoints, счетчик перестал совсем вызываться. В чем проблема может быть?

```html
<section id="testing">
            <span class="timer" data-from="25" data-speed="100" data-to="999"></span>
</section>
```

```js
var start = new Waypoint({
            element: document.getElementById('testing'),
            handler: function () {
                $('.timer').countTo();
            }
        });
```

В консоле ошибок нет

Comment: надо чтобы счётчик работал только если его видо на экране?

Comment: @Horchynskyi да

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так
У меня в полном окне страницы работает

```js
var count = 0;
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
});
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();;
var windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
setInterval(function(){
    if(scrollTop <= $('#counter').offset().top && (scrollTop + windowHeight) >= $('#counter').offset().top){
        console.log(count);
        $('#counter').text(++count);
    }
}, 1000)
```

```css
body{
  height:5000px;
}
#counter{
  width: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter">0</div>
```